# Should I pay my rental car company a speeding and toll ticket in Canada?

Tags: legal, canada, car-rentals, tolls

Today I got an invoice from a major, world-wide known car rental company. It seems that I have used a toll express highway without paying and I also got a speeding ticket during my vacation in Canada. I don't want to discuss the ethics here, but is there any drawback if I don't pay the bill? Would I get into trouble when trying to rent a car with the same rental company?

Comment: Was a similar question asked before? Meanwhile, watch out for drones and Navy SEALs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I have to pay traffic fines issued by foreign governments?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/do-i-have-to-pay-traffic-fines-issued-by-foreign-governments)

Comment: It is similar, but I'm more concerned about the rental car company.

Comment: But as far as I understand, this site is about travel matters, not legal matters ...

Comment: It is, but around 50% of the time I travel I rent cars ;)

Comment: The question is about a bill you don't want to pay and the consequences it will have for you. The object of the bill does not matter.

Comment: That's why I wrote this in the question: " I don't want to discuss the ethics here."

Comment: I think this is a very legit question and voted for reopen. You might want to change the title though to reflect that this is about rental agencies abroad and not generic about not paying tickets and tolls. There is already a question on that topic. 
But whether or not to pay an invoice sent after the rental ends interests me very much due to bad experience with quite some rentals in the past.

Comment: @Andra Thanks for the hint, I edited the title.

Comment: Changing the title does not change the essence. It remains a purely legal matter. No real travel content

Comment: @MarcelC. That's your opinion...

Comment: @MarcelC. It is a legal question. So what? The situation described here only applies to travelers. You might disagree on the ethical part, but that is no reason to be against this question. BTW there is even a tag "legal".

Comment: @Andra the legal tag is for question about "what is permitted or forbidden". And I think that there is no doupt, that's not permitted not to pay your tickets. It's possible that he doesn't get into trouble, but it's still not permitted

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you rented the car with a credit card, you will have signed something that says they can charge these things to your credit card and it's not disputable. The only speed-camera ticket I ever got was in a rental car (and they tacked on a handling fee to boot.) It took weeks to come through, but it came as a charge on my credit card.

If you had driven your own car on the 407 and then not paid the toll, there would be consequences for the car. (At one point, you couldn't renew your license plates if you had outstanding tolls against that plate.) Presumably the car people have paid the toll so that their car can still function. You now owe them the money.

I am completely sure you've signed something that holds you liable for these charges. Since you're describing an invoice, you must have rented the car with cash or cheque. Whether to pay or not now is no different than if you had ordered something and then not paid for it once it was delivered. The country as a whole is not in the habit of enforcing these sorts of debts, so you probably won't be nabbed at the border, but you can be certain that the rental company will keep track of you. If they hand the debt to a collection company, it's possible the collector would find it worthwhile to harass you from a distance. They can be pretty nasty.

To me it's simple. You signed that you would pay such things. Pay it. If it's a lot of money and you can't afford it right now, contact them and tell them so, and arrange to pay it over time. But pay it. And next time stay off the toll highways (they're clearly signed) if it's not your intention to pay the toll.