# Non payment of red light ticket in Atlanta on Indian drivers' license

Tags: usa, legal, driving, georgia-usa, indian-citizens

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens when a foreigner gets a speeding ticket in the United States?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/995/what-happens-when-a-foreigner-gets-a-speeding-ticket-in-the-united-states)

I was issued a red light ticket in Atlanta. Officer told me I could pay that online after 7 days, but the ticket was never received in their system. I checked with them by calling them but they say it will be there next time, every time. Can I enter US again or  more specifically Atlanta, GA ?